# Tests for maven plugins are incompatible with maven 3.0.4

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, maven-plugin

I have a simple test for maven plugin:

```
public class SimpleMavenTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        // code
    }

    public void testCase() throws Exception {
        // test case
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // code
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

with such [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) configuration:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Until maven 3.0.4 has been released, my SimpleMavenTest run succesfully. But when I run the test using maven 3.0.4, the next error was occurred:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The internal default plexus-bootstrap.xml is missing. This is highly irregular, your plexus JAR is most likely corrupt.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initializeConfiguration(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1052)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initialize(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:627)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusTestCase.setUp(PlexusTestCase.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.setUp(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:69)
    at org.maven.test.MyMojoTest.setUp(MyMojoTest.java:12)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I looked here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html and tried to change *maven-surefire-plugin* configuration in a such way:

```
<configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
</configuration>
```

Everything works fine. But if I make:

```
<forkMode>never</forkMode>
```

the above error is occured. It's strange, because on maven 3.0.3 and previous maven versions the test was run without any errors. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the similiar setup but I have version info on my surefire config which is listed like this  <version>${surefire.version}</version> . not sure if it might help. can u try it?

Comment: do u have an entry for this group id in your pom? <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>

Comment: I tried to add <version>${surefire.version}</version>, but the error was occurred again.

I have this entry: <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>. I replaced it with your try: <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId> and test run succesfylly. Thanks for your help!
But I need it works with <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> and as I wrote above, it's interesting: why it works on maven 3.0.3 and doesn't work on maven 3.0.4.

Comment: I ran into this issue last week found it unusual though. I will try to bruteforce it and see what happens. if you want i can list that as an answer to this post.

Comment: If you find some solution, please, post it here. I will also continue my searches in this trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened [a bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-835) on jira.codehaus.org and got the answer that this trouble was resolved in maven-surefire-plugin v.2.11. As I used 2.10 version, the error was occurred. The latest surefire plugin version is 2.12, so change surefire configuration as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and tests will run successfully.